# Custom DataGridViewRow problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create a custom DataGridViewRow that will act as separator (to divide data into groups). I did it by overriding the PainCells method in DataGridViewRow class like this:

```
protected override void PaintCells(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, bool isFirstDisplayedRow, bool isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {  
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackgroundColor),rowBounds);

        StringFormat format = new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center};
        graphics.DrawString(Text, this.DataGridView.Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), rowBounds,format);
    }
```

Where Text, BackgroundColor and ForeColor are properties of my SeparatorDataGridViewRow class. The rows look exactly like I wanted them to. But this is only the "cover" because below the drawn rectangle there are still original datagrid cells. In particular the cell with delete button form DataGridViewButtonColumn which i added. And because of that if I click on the cell where button is my separator row is deleted.

I dont think this is the right way to achive what i want to achive so i would be glad if you guys could either show me the right direction or tell what i could do with this solution to block the user possibility to do anything with this row no matter what is "below the drawn rectagle".

I have little experience in creating custom controls so I dont really know what methods to override or what to add to achieve certain goals.
Every help appreciated :)

Comment: Is there any way to tell DataGridView not to draw cells in given row. Or in given type of the row? I could not find any method responsible for that. DataGridView onPaint method gives only ClipRectangle and Graphics as parameter so I cant determine which row is he drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem partially. I don’t know if this solution is good and it brings another problem which is a mystery to me.

On my SeparatorDataGridViewRow I set Tag to "Separator". Then I created my own DataGridView control in which I override OnUserDeletingRow method:

```
    protected override void OnUserDeletingRow(DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.Tag != null && e.Row.Tag.ToString().Equals("Separator"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        base.OnUserDeletingRow(e);
    }
```

This way my Separator row can’t be deleted by user. But now strange things happens. I have a DataGridView like this:

[image]

When I select row with name "2" and deleted it everything works fine:

[image]

And it works with all rows. BUT if i select any of the Separator rows and press Delete it won’t get deleted but if then i delete any of the rows above it this happens:

[image]

In this case I selected Separator 2 then deleted row named "2". Its strange because the actual row is being deleted and the selected row is in fact Separator2 row. It’s some kind of Paint problem. But I don’t know why this happens only when i "try" to delete Separator row before. What changes in Painting process when i try to delete Separator row before deleting any of the above?